# probability that exactly one carriage is empty

Tags: probability, combinatorics

10 people get in to the train which has 4 carriages. What is the probability that exactly one carriage is empty?

Sample space is 10 digitals strings, each digit takes some value from 1 to 4. Order of sample space is $4^{10}$

How to calculate order of event that exactly one carriage is empty? I tried ${4 \choose 1}{10 \choose 3}3!3^7$. Choose which carriage is empty, choose $3$ people and place them in $3$ different carriages so exactly one is empty and then $7$ people can go to any of $3$ carriages which was not chosen to be empty. However this  is wrong, I count some situation more than one time, for example if we choose fourth carriage to be empty choose people with numbers $1$ $2$ and $3$ to go to first, second and third carriage respectively and then let other seven people to go to first carriage, and the same situation happening differently is choose fourth carriage to be empty, choose people with numbers $10$ $2$ and $3$ to go to first, second and third carriage respectively and then let other seven people go to first carriage.

If solution is tricky, I mean basing on the fact that there are only $4$ carriages, is there a general method for $n$ people and $k$ carriages and exactly $m$ to be empty?

Answer (score 0):

There are $N_3=4$ ways to have 3 carriages empty

for 2 empty carriages there are $\binom 42$ ways to choose which carriages to occupy, for each of these choices there are $2^{10}$ ways to occupy the cars, but 2 of these are cases in which everyone is in a single car

so for exactly 2 empty $N_2= \binom 42 (2^{10} - 2)$

to have  1 car empty there are $\binom 43$ ways to choose which cars are occupied, for each of these choices, there are  $3^{10}$ ways to occupy the cars, but 3 of those will have everyone in a single car, and $\binom 32 (2^{10} - 2)$ ways will have everyone in 2 cars.

so for exactly 1 carriage empty the number of ways is
$$N_1 =  \binom 43 \left [ (3^{10} - 3)-\binom 32 (2^{10}-2) \right ]$$